# How to get post id of last approved comment?

Tags: posts, comments, id

Can you help me with something simple?

How can I get the post id of the last approved comment? I want to assign it to a variable.

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$recent_comments = get_comments( array(
    'number'    => 1,
    'status'    => 'approve'
) );
foreach($recent_comments as $comment) :
    $latest_postid_with_comment = $comment->comment_post_ID;
endforeach;
?>
```

Probably way to compress this code into something smaller. But this will work.

Comment: Thanks so much Weston. What do I do if there are no approved comments yet? I would like to set it to the first post then. How should I do that?